# Can I hide associated accounts on my public CV?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, flair

It would be really nice if there was a way to select which associated accounts to show on your public CV.

Frankly, I'd like to keep it limited to just my SO account the way the private CV is.   I'm not sure if it is useful or productive for a potential employer to look through my MSO posts about waffles for example.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Potential employers may see an interest in waffles as offensive and politically incorrect

Comment: I don't think I want to work for employers who are bigoted against waffles... or ponies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We're going to refactor account association this weekend (I hope) - I'll add this option to Careers while I'm in there.

Update:  We have added the ability to hide associated accounts.  Visit the "associate accounts" tab and choose the ones you would like to be visible.

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem

Comment: Will it also address this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29880/make-it-possible-to-un-associate-your-so-account-from-your-careers-account

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Actually, showing the Meta Stack Overflow flair is meaningless...what does it matter?It shouldn't even be an option to show it.</strike> The <strike>other</strike> flair should be reorderable and toggable.

EDIT: If one person thinks that the Meta flair should at least be an option, and it's already there, then it should stay an option.

Comment: I want my Meta flair on my CV

Comment: Nevermind that first part, then. I guess they should all be toggable and reorderable.

Answer (score 3):

+1, I was about to suggest the exact same thing.

I'm a developer, but have found serverfault and superuser useful. While it's good to show my development knowledge on my CV, I'm not so sure that showing that I have also asked a few questions on each of the other sites is any use at all.

Answer (score 2):

I was also just about to ask the same question, I have no issue with showing my SO rep but my pathetic 101 on meta and superuser don't need to be seen by the whole world.

Answer (score 0):

If you've linked your accounts, then all a potential employer needs to do is go to your "preferred" account from CSO, then look at other posts on the sister sites via the <kbd>Accounts</kbd> tab there.

Comment: This is true, but a viewer would have know about the accounts tab, and they'd have to take the initiative to look it up.   This is very different than just putting it in their face on the main CV page.