# select the flair displayed on the CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I hide associated accounts on my public CV?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/can-i-hide-associated-accounts-on-my-public-cv)

I like the flair being displayed on my CV, but only the SO flair.

I have very low rep in the other sites ( SF for instance I have just 200 pts )

Is it considered to allow the user to select which flair will be displayed?

Also, if I want to change the picture ( for one where I'm using a tie )  would there be a change to do that with out having to show that tie in the SO site it self?

;)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/can-i-hide-associated-accounts-on-my-public-cv

Comment: That's the one I want! thanks Shog9