# Change order of associated account badges on public CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

At the moment my public CV lists all 4 accounts in the trilogy. SO is listed first, however I have the most rep on SF, and will be looking for jobs in the sysadmin area, can we have the CV either list the badges in order of Rep, or allow us to re-order them?

I see no reason for SO to always come first if all sites are created equal?

Comment: There is already a question about hiding certain sites, but I can't find it.

Comment: Just found it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27771/can-i-hide-associated-accounts-on-my-public-cv

Comment: Ah ok, i'll remove the bit about hiding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably make sense for them to be displayed in order of your reputation on the sites - since that's almost certainly a reasonable indicator of which you're going to want to show first.