# Make it possible to unassociate your SO account from your Careers account?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, linked-accounts

Is there any reason why it's not possible to un-link your SO account from your Careers account?

Comment: Why not just clean up the question? That will benefit everybody and not just yourself.

Comment: Edits are still visible.  I think it's a fair request -- not everyone wants to go public. Some even choose nicknames and mysterious avatars in order to hide a bit.

Comment: But edits will also show others how you've improved in your learning and that's got to be a good thing.

Comment: Something like "Clear All Associations" on your SO profile?

Comment: you could also delete the question

Comment: @Ether: If you didn't want to go public, and choose a nickname or avatar, why would you associate your SO profile with your careers account anyway?

Comment: @womble: I think the association happened automatically via the choice of OpenID; it's not something I recall setting up manually. In my case I'm not hell-bent on anonymity; I just don't like my name popping up a million times in google. I'm not hard to find if you're really intent on it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even serious and helpful answers can be reason to deny you a job position.  For example, I know that showing any liking for perl disqualifies you as a serious developer in the eyes of my boss.

So if SO Careers links your real name to "tainted" SO questions, it would be useful to be able to unlink it.  Maybe you can even write up some perl hate and link it to your new avatar!

Comment: yes, but that's a problem with your Boss, and not Stack Overflow

Comment: @andomar: I guess we're never going to work together then..

Comment: @Ether: You're assuming YOU'RE the one who's looking for a new job? hehe

Comment: Sure, but this is not an answer

Answer (score 12):

Kelso, based on the questions you've asked here, I am not sure our careers feature matches *anything* you want to do.

I think we have a bad fit here. No point in pushing a relationship that isn't going to work out for either one of us. No harm, no foul, everybody walks away.

Please email us for a refund at the address linked at the bottom of every careers.stackoverflow.com page -- we'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: hehe, sarcasm? but still, that's harsh

Comment: Jeff: Maybe but I'm curious why this request is not feasible.

Comment: Kelso: I think the issue is about the genral culutre of openness. Careers seems to be about making it easy to show what you really are about. It's not about *choosing* how you *want* to present yourself, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Since SO content is licensed under CC-Wiki, you should be able to request that the team disassociate any questions/answers that you don't want linked to your account from it.  This is one of the moral rights that the CC-Wiki license retains to you -- the ability to remove your name from any of your content.

> In addition to the right of licensors
>   to request removal of their name from
>   the work when used in a derivative or
>   collective they don't like, copyright
>   laws in most jurisdictions around the
>   world (with the notable exception of
>   the US except in very limited
>   circumstances) grant creators "moral
>   rights" which may provide some redress
>   if a derivative work represents a
>   "derogatory treatment" of the
>   licensor's work.

Answer (score 5):

The point of listing yourself on careers is for the association with your SO identity, otherwise it's just another CV database.  So if you don't want that, maybe you're really looking for something else.