# Hide other SE accounts

Tags: feature-request, support, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I like to use my real name and photo on some Stack Exchange sites that are relevant to my career (e.g. Stack Overflow) but use a pseudonym on other Stack Exchange sites (such as Gaming). Partly, because I want that if possible employers Google my name they see relevant things for my career, not me commenting on games or that sort of stuff.

Right now if I go to a new SE site automatically a new account is created with my name. I can change the name and e-mail, but there is still a tab with my other accounts. Is there a way to hide this?

I found this question: [Can I hide associated accounts on my public CV?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27771/157142) but that is only about CVs.

Comment: Sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it.

Comment: This should be a feature request, since the option to hide accounts is not currently available (AFAIK).

Comment: I asked something similar earlier today and GraceNote responded, *"We are looking into clean and functional ways to handle that as well."*

Comment: has there been any update on this since 2011?

Comment: Related: [Allow users to hide connections between accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/allow-users-to-hide-connections-between-accounts)

Answer (score 10):

Why not create a second OpenID for gaming and use that instead of the one you used for your Stack Overflow account. There's no rule that states you *have* to use the same OpenID for all your accounts. The only drawback to this would be that you wouldn't get the association bonus for your gaming account, but that's not a big issue.

This way you could have two sets of accounts - one for your "serious" topics, the other for the more "frivolous" ones.

Comment: I considered this but I don't really like to log out and log in all the time.

Comment: @Zagga I think that since each site is logged onto separately, that would only be an issue if you had multiple accounts on the same sites, which is not what it seems you would be doing.

Comment: And one for [sec.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/human-sexual-response-and-non-platonic-relations)...

Comment: why not add a nice and convenient feature?

Comment: @MK01 - possibly. I was just pointing out that you can do what the OP wants with the current system.

Comment: @Zagga - That's really all we're going to support, making the accounts tab filterable isn't planned at all, in fact we're very much against it.

Comment: @NickCraver You are against it, as developers or users? As a UX designer, I think, that's the users who can specify the necessity a feature. This is harming the user's privacy and doesn't make sence to say: Just create another account. -1

Comment: @NickCraver Why is Stack Exchange against this? Just generally against configuration options, or something deeper? This is a post I periodically point people to (and in fact wanted myself) so an official "We are rejecting this because ..." would be useful. Creating a completely separate account for me isn't practical because I wouldn't receive notifications on a rarely used account

Comment: Although looking at a duplicate of this [Jeff may have already provided an official response of sorts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85985/220332)