# Option to hide specific accounts on profile summary

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-accounts

[My profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/195862/danny-beckett)'s summary tab has this widget (not sure what these boxes are referred to internally as):

> [image]

I would like the option to hide *English Language Learners* from this list.

The reason being that, to the casual passer-by, it kind of implies I'm learning English; which 
isn't good if employers look at my profile, from my CV/resume on *Careers*.

I wouldn't mind if it the account itself was still shown on the [image] link, but it would be great to be able to remove it, just from my profile summary. A simple checkbox next to each account would suffice.

The resultant effect for me would be:

> [image]

(to be honest I'd probably also hide *Area 51*, leaving *Android Enthusiasts* as my last account).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115789/152859 in your case Chris answer is valid course of action, just use whole different account. You would lose the +100 bonus but will enjoy anonymity.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's a good related question (the possible duplicate within that question is even better). It's not a case of anonymity that I'm after though; I don't mind all of my accounts showing in the *view more* link - I'd just like to be able to customise what's shown in this "widget".

Comment: I suppose I can see the reasoning there. Having the accounts actually linked is very convenient, and I can imagine that some prospective employers might have looked dimly on my previous membership on, say, the firearms site we had.