# How connected are stack sites' profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, linked-accounts

I just registered on another stack site that is more of a hobby related, while Stack Overflow is more work related and I do not necessarily want them to be connected. For example in Stack Exchange I use my real name (do not even see the reason to hide it), but for Anime & Manga I do not necessarily  want to use it and I definitely do not want it's account to be visible in SO. You know one is work and the other is my private interests.

I think I did manage to change my profile name in Anime & Manga but I am not sure it that will reflect in SO any time soon as well. In general I would like to make the two accounts very different. And I do not know if I can and I do not want to mess with my SO account (I like it as it is).

From this ([Allow users to hide connections between accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/allow-users-to-hide-connections-between-accounts)) feature request I get it that what I currently want can't be done, but what exactly can I do without effecting my SO profile?

Comment: Your profiles can have different display names, no problem. Just browse around Meta around christmas time to see everyone use seasonal names just here, leaving their SO profiles untouched.

Comment: @Martijn What about pictures and stuff like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your accounts will be linked if you use the same OpenID login for both accounts.

However, you are free to change any of the publicly visible fields, including the:

- Display Name
- Birthday
- Profile picture
- About me section

individually *per site*. Just make sure you click the 'Save Profile' button, not the 'Save and Copy' button.

Comment: Yay, I can have a birthday every day! (Um, well, every week at least. Still need a few more sites before we reach 365.)

Answer (score 4):

The profiles will not be linked content wise. However, there will be a link from your Anime profile and your Stack Overflow profile in the Accounts section.

In order to truly separate these profiles, you would need to use two different accounts. If you did this, you would have to avoid the automerge feature though, which can happen if both accounts are logged in at the same time on the same browser.

Comment: To keep your accounts separated, use different OpenID credentials and never let them mix.